# Cython returning a double complex to a float complex causes the expression not to be in pure C

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

I have a problem trying to use complex64_t in Cython. Here is my simple cython example.

```
cimport numpy as cnp

cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double complex cexp(double complex)

cpdef example():
    cdef float b = 2.0
    cdef cnp.complex64_t temp1
    cdef cnp.complex128_t temp2

    temp1 = cexp(1j * b)
    temp2 = cexp(1j * b)
```

When I cythonize the file with the following setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import numpy as np


ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "bug_example",
        ["bug_example.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
    )
]


setup(
    name='bug_example',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, annotate=True,
                          compiler_directives={'boundscheck': False})
)
```

Everything compiles with no problems, but I get yellow (not pure C) on the line containing

```
temp1 = cexp(1j * b)
```

But not on

```
temp2 = cexp(1j * b)
```

This seems to be a problem returning a double complex to a float complex. I have tried casting it explicit to float complex like:

```
temp1 = <float complex>(cexp(1j * b))
```

But that doesn't make a difference.

Can someone help me fix my code so the line with temp1 doesn't have any more yellow and is pure C. This will allow me to use openmp in cython.

Comment: Is it actually using any Python API calls (or blocking openmp in any other way)? The annotation coloring is, as it says, a hint; if you click the `+` sign and look at the C code, what is it doing? I'd think it ought to be calling some macro or inline function defined further up the C file that just does something like `(x) + (y)*(_CYTHON_COMPLEX_64_I_CONST_HERE)` if it's not using Python (plus macro calls to get the real and imag parts of a Cython complex128), which you should be able to verify pretty easily.

Comment: … although it will probably be messy, because, IIRC, Cython writes alternate versions of each of those macros for C++98, C11, C99, and C89 and switches between them by checking preprocessor flags.

Comment: Also, you're not specifying a language. If you build for C89, it's going to use structs for complex64 and complex128, which isn't nearly as slow as going to Python or anything, but still isn't as nice as the builtin C complex types (and can be incorrect for cases involving infinity, IIRC).

Comment: Which compiler are you using? if it is gcc, then I doubt that this line prevents the usage of openmp, because the macro `__Pyx_CREAL` expands to `__real__` extension.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow color is due to `__Pyx_CREAL` and `__Pyx_CIMAG` which shouldn't be an issue, but who knows...

In order to avoid it you have to avoid the casting from `double` to `float` and back.

For example:

```
cimport numpy as cnp

#take the float version (cexpf) instead of double-version (cexp)
cdef extern from "complex.h":
     float complex cexpf(float complex)

#1j maps to double complex, so create a float version
cdef float complex float_1j = 1j

cpdef example():
    cdef float b_float = 2.0                              #use float not double
    cdef cnp.complex64_t temp1 = cexpf(float_1j*b_float)  #everything is float
```